# How to get who/when changed the work item type in vsts?

Tags: azure-devops

When we are doing the customization of a work item type in VSTS. Do we also have the ability to **track the history of the customization itself**?

[image]

For example, we are trying to find out when the start date field was added to our customized Bug work item type.

A field was not there in a previous Increment but we noticed it recently. Just want to find out **if there is a date captured somewhere that tells us when it was added or who may have added it**?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately we cannot get the information from VSTS for now. No date or history included from the retrieved process information via REST API.

However there's already a [user voice submitted here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/9858555-add-activity-log-to-tfs-online-to-track-user-acces) to suggest the feature to add Activity Log to VSTS to track user accesses, you can go and vote it up or submit a new one to suggest the feature again to achieve that is future release.

For now as a workaround we suggest that you can ask the team members to add corresponding comments in description area after completing the customization for the process... Thus you can track the history of the customization...

[image]